# Listening to key events for a component hierarchy

Tags: java, events, swing, keylistener

I have a Swing app that needs to display different sets of controls based on whether the control or alt keys are pressed.  I added a KeyListener to the main component, but it is notified only if that component is selected, not if a subcomponent is selected.  Is there a way to listen to events for a component and all descendents?

**Edit:**

I tried using the main component's InputMap, but no event is fired when pressing a modifier key.  Specifically, I have the following code:

```
InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed CONTROL"), "test1");
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released CONTROL"), "test2");
ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();
actionMap.put("test1", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("pressed");
    }
});
actionMap.put("test2", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("released");
    }
});
```

When pressing and releasing the control key, this will print "released" but not "pressed".  Nothing else is registering anything in any InputMap, so it's not as though something else is registered for the same key stroke.

Answer (score 4):

Just change your `getKeyStroke(...)` invocation like so:

```
InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK, false), "test1");
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, 0, true), "test2");
ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();
actionMap.put("test1", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("pressed");
    }
});
actionMap.put("test2", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("released");
    }
});
```

I took me a lot of trial and error to come up with the correct incantation.

It is important to use getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT), to be able to listen to child and deeper widgets.

It is especially important to specify `KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK`, in addition to `KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL` when looking for control key PRESS events. This particular detail was missing from your modified code example.

Comment: I had problems with `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` and found it more useful to use `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try to use key binding rather than KeyListeners.  Key binding is a higher level construct and can listen for key presses even if the component that "listens" doesn't have the focus -- as opposed to KeyListeners.  You can find more on these at the Swing tutorials: [How to use key bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using [the InputMap and ActionMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) of some swing components. You can specify with `JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` to indicate you want to respond to the given keystroke when either the component or its subcomponents are in focus.

If you don't want to use the InputMap or ActionMap, you could just add the KeyListener to all the child components:

```
for (Component child : parent.getComponents())
{
 child.addKeyListener(keyListener);
}
```

Comment: This works for "released CONTROL" KeyStrokes but not for "pressed CONTROL".  Likewise for alt and shift.

Comment: @Adam Crume Well, some controls may be listening themselves to ctrl, alt, or shift. However, at least testing with other keystrokes, it launches the given action at key press. Admittedly, though, it will repeatedly launch while the keystroke is pressed down.

Comment: What Zack mentions with InputMap and ActionMap is using key bindings.  Again, check the tutorial it will solve your problem.

Comment: No, the tutorial does not solve my problem.  InputMap does not work for this situation.  I found that changing the press KeyStroke to "ctrl pressed CONTROL" will respond to the control key presses, but there's another problem:  I want to know when the control key is pressed, regardless of whether alt/altGr/shift/meta are pressed or not.  This is not possible without adding 16 key strokes for each modifier key press that I care about.  I'm going with this instead: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip69.html

Comment: @Adam Crume ok dok. But the info in the tutorial both Hovercraft Full Of Eels and I provided is still good to know for future. Good luck with you app!

Comment: It is good to know for other things; it just doesn't solve this problem.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a [Global Event Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/).